# Using PNG instead of JPG images to fix Outlook rendering issues?

Tags: css, outlook, media-queries, png, html-email

Our HTML email templates look great in every ESP except outlook 120 DPI. The suggested blog tips to this point have not worked.

Has anyone tried using PNG images instead ofJPG images in their emails?  Has this helped solve image rendering issues or caused and additional issues?

I've tried editing my tables and media queries through various blog  tips such as the ones in https://litmus.com/blog/mastering-outlook-a-look-back-at-common-rendering-issues. I can get every ESP to render our templates properly, but not Outlook 120 DPI

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=edge" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Smartsheet</title> 

    <!-- Default Styles --> 
    <style type="text/css">
            .ExternalClass {
                width: 100%;
            }
            .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {
                line-height: 100%;
            }
            table { 
                border-spacing: 0px !important; 
                mso-table-lspace: 0pt; 
                mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
                table-layout: fixed;
            }
            table table { 
                table-layout: auto; 
            }
            h2,h2 a,h2 a:visited,h3,h3 a,h3 a:visited,h4,h5,h6,.t_cht {
                  color: #363639;
            }
            @-ms-viewport { 
                width: device-width; 
            }
            h1, h2, h3, h4 {
                font-weight: normal;
            }
```

The code above should contain the basic CSS needed to understand my problem and the HTML. As yo should be able to see, the image in the tile is blown out of proportion. This happens for all of our images in outlook 120 DPI .

Comment: Hey there, you'll need to post more code for us to help you out. Screenshots would also be helpful but code if your best bet.

For your image issue, changing file format will not help you here. Don't worry about saving out as a PNG. 
Providing code for us to debug will help us pick up any issues with how you're declaring your image dimensions.

Comment: Thanks. I think i fixed the code so you can see my main issues.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 120DPI will look bigger because that is the entire point of it. It's a zooming feature.

If it doesn't scale properly, you need to add the following code, courtesy of [Email on Acid](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/dpi_scaling_in_outlook_2007-2013/):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
  <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG/>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
  </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
```